# How to change column type in SQL view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Maybe sounds like a dumb question but here is my situation:

I have a table with integer type field (name PartnerID).
I need to create a view on this table and adds (actually replaces) leading zeros to the integer field.

Example for field (PartnerID)
11235
11567
11567
22789
22657
22456
33567

Should be (in view):
00235
00567
00567
00789
00657
00456
33567

Since thats impossible what are my options?

EDIT: Im not adding zeros im replacing.

Here is the current formula for the field PartnerID in the view, but this just ignores the leading zeros. I want to have leading zeros based on this formula in my view.

```
CASE WHEN (LEN(PartnerID) = 5 AND (PartnerID LIKE '11%' OR
                      PartnerID LIKE '22%')) THEN stuff(PartnerID, 1, 2, '00') ELSE PartnerId END AS PartnerID
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the Integer PartnerId to a string e.g:

```
CASE WHEN (LEN(PartnerID) = 5 AND (PartnerID LIKE '11%' OR
                      PartnerID LIKE '22%')) THEN stuff(PartnerID, 1, 2, '00') ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), PartnerId) END AS PartnerID
```

Comment: It's about making sure everything is a string, and nothing is still an integer, then nothing will get trimmed

Comment: interesting. Im not sure i understand ... i only see conversion after the ELSE. Where is it converted when the STUFF happens (in the case portion)?

Comment: STUFF should return as a string already, so only one conversion needed

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think this is not possible?

Would something like this not work

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,IntegerColumn), 5) FROM YourTable
```

Comment: @no9, you need to clarify your question, what are you trying to achieve?